# How to run wvdial for modem?

Tags: linux, kernel, embedded, modem

I have some problem during trying run command "wvdial", because i got error like:

```
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Warning: section [Dialer Defaults] does not exist in wvdial.conf.
--> Cannot open /dev/modem: No such file or directory
--> Cannot open /dev/modem: No such file or directory
--> Cannot open /dev/modem: No such file or directory
```

Before executing this command i did "wvdialconf" and i got:

```
Editing `/etc/wvdial.conf'.

Scanning your serial ports for a modem.

Modem Port Scan<*1>: S0   S1   S2   S3   
ttyUSB0<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 -- OK
ttyUSB0<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 Z -- OK
ttyUSB0<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 -- OK
ttyUSB0<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 -- OK
ttyUSB0<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 -- OK
ttyUSB0<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0 -- OK
ttyUSB0<*1>: Modem Identifier: ATI -- 332
ttyUSB0<*1>: Speed 4800: AT -- OK
ttyUSB0<*1>: Speed 9600: AT -- OK
ttyUSB0<*1>: Speed 19200: AT -- OK
ttyUSB0<*1>: Speed 38400: AT -- OK
ttyUSB0<*1>: Speed 57600: AT -- OK
ttyUSB0<*1>: Speed 115200: AT -- OK
ttyUSB0<*1>: Speed 230400: AT -- OK
ttyUSB0<*1>: Speed 460800: AT -- Speed 460800: AT -- Speed 460800: AT -- Max speed is 230400; that should be safe.
ttyUSB0<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0 -- OK

Found a modem on /dev/ttyUSB0.
Modem configuration written to /etc/wvdial.conf.
ttyUSB0<Info>: Speed 230400; init "ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0"
```

My "wvdial.conf" file looks:

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
Modem Type = Analog Modem
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
Baud = 115200


Phone = *99#
Username = " "
Password = " "
Stupid Mode = 1
Init3 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","my_apn"
```

What could be cousing my problem? I use my own linux distribution build by "buildroot". (I specially changed the name of apn to "my_apn"). When I do it by analogy on raspberry pi everything works fine.

When I do "sudo wvdial -c" I see:

```
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Warning: section [Dialer Defaults] does not exist in wvdial.conf.
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
--> Sending: ATQ0
--> Re-Sending: ATZ
--> Modem not responding.
```

I have the same configuration on raspberry pi and it works. My modem Telit GT863-PY